# In "And, today, we're..." why would "today" be offset by commas?

Tags: punctuation

I am in the middle of a debate and am hoping some of you can help me understand. Why would the word “today” in the sentence below be offset with commas? Some say the word is nonessential; therefore, it requires a comma before and one after. Some say it’s an introductory word; therefore, it only needs one comma after “today.”  What say you?

> And, today, we're going to be talking about repairing some...

Comment: Just to confuse the issue, my preference is with no commas. (A comma is optional in such a short introductory clause.) But you could argue for both of the cases you've stated depending on the context.

Comment: So I take it your voting for the word being part of an introductory clause/word?

Comment: Well more on the fence. I think both are correct. Stylistically if I can imagine more situations where the introductory comma position would be used.

Answer (score -2):

I can understand and would personally use the comma after TODAY, but I don't understand the one after AND. It seems totally unnecessary there, unless something was previously stated for TODAY and this is in addition: Today, we're going to look at the parts of an engine and take one apart. And, today, we're going to be talking about repairing..." But even this seems clumsy.

Comment: Those who argue two commas say “today” is nonrestrictive/unnessential. Those arguing the word iscintroductory say one comma after “today”